# How to optimize deleting row in batches in a loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still learning and trying to understand things in SQL. I have a script that is doing deletes in batches like this:

```
while rows_were_deleted:
    DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM deletes_table) LIMIT 1000
```

And this is pretty slow. My first thought was that `SELECT id FROM deletes_table` was taking a long time since `deletes_table` had a few thousand rows. So I tried something more like

```
while rows_were_deleted:
    ids_to_delete = SELECT id FROM deletes_table
    for delete_id in ids_to_deletes:
        DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id = delete_id LIMIT 1000
```

And this was even slower. I'm guessing because there is so many more operations. What is the best way to do deletes like this?

Comment: Is there more than one row to delete for each `WHERE id = delete_id`

Comment: Usually, yes. However, the number will be different for each `delete_id`

Comment: Seems a little strange to use a LIMIT! Do you want to leave rows on the table if for example there would have been 1001 row that match the where clause

Comment: I am using the LIMIT because there might be billions of rows to delete, so I'm worried about `timeout` errors, or that the connection might die in some other way.

Comment: Out of interest, How long is _very slow_

Comment: And how long is _even slower_

Comment: And how many rows are there in the table that you are deleting from and how many indexes are there on that table

Comment: After watching the results for a couple days, we figured that the first method would take about 6 years to complete, and the second method about 20 years

Comment: There are about 10 billions rows and 1 index.

Comment: Another silly question from me: How long does it take to do a single `DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id = 1`

Comment: That I'm not sure about because of permissions

Comment: Can you not find one id from your delete_me table that only has a few rows to delete from the main table?

Comment: I can, but it's more of a permissions problem because it's a production database and I'd prefer not to manually delete like that.

Comment: And I assume it's too big a database to take a copy an put it on a testing version

Comment: Yes, it is too big. I'm working on making a testing DB right now

Answer (score 0):

```
while rows_were_deleted:
    DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM deletes_table) LIMIT 1000
```

You can try adding limit to `select id from deletes_tables` also.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't give much improvement. I also was thinking about doing the `SELECT id FROM deletes_table` once and storing that result in memory and using that in each `DELETE FROM some_table` after